# Repeat loop having no effect in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to access elevation data using the "elevatr" package in R. I have a large set of coordinates (over 5,000 points) that I have set in a data frame, which is how the package is suppose to work. However, I have found that the connection gets interrupted regularly and the entire calculation stops.

I want to use a repeat loop to make sure the calculation runs its entirety, and when it fails, it starts over again on its own. However, the first few times I have tried, the repeat loop seems to have no effect and the calculation doesn't start over again.

I left a sample of my code. "n" is my desired length, which is pre-set. Everything in the code I provided works. Its just that sometimes get_elev_points does not complete the calculation, and putting it in a repeat loop does not seem to have any effect.

Any advice on the best way to solve this problem?

```
    library(elevatr)
    library(rgdal)

    e <- 0
    elevation <- 0
    ll_prj <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

    repeat{
      coordinates <- data.frame(lon,lat)
      e <- get_elev_point(locations = coordinates[m,], units="feet", prj = ll_prj)
      elevation <- e$elevation
      if (length(elevation) == n) {
        break
      }}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `repeat()` with round brackets, not `repeat{}`?